# Why or when should I use bit shifts in enum like this?

Tags: c++, enums, bit-fields

While studying enums, I have seen some people use them in combination with bit shifting. Being a beginner and unsure of correct usage, I would appreciate advice.

So here are 2 examples.

```
#define BIT(x) (1<<x)

enum WithBits{`

    first = BIT(0), //first = 1
    second = BIT(1), // second = 2
    third = BIT(2) //third = 4  }
```

`BIT(x)` is defined where each of `enum` members has value of 1 shifted x times to the left. For example `x` of member `third` is 2. 1 is shifted 2 times so `third` is connected with value 4. In the end, values of `first` , `second` and `third` are 1, 2 and 4 respectively.

Now we could also do this.

```
enum WithoutBits{`

    first = 1, // first = 1
    second = 2, // second = 2
    third = 4 // third = 4  }
```

In this case, `first`, `second` and `third` are also 1, 2 and 4.
Both examples work fine.
What exactly is the difference? Why and when should I use first `enum` example (`WithBits`) instead of second example (`WithoutBits`)?
Thanks you for your time, any help is welcome!

Comment: Probably never.

Comment: The first mistake you made is with the absolutely pointless macro that only confuses people more than anything else.

Comment: Otherwise, the two are identical. What you're doing is not called bit fields. [Bit fields are something else](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).

Comment: `BIT(x)` is arguably more readable, but I agree with John Zwink's answer. The readability gain from such a simple macro is negligible. Better just use `1<<x` directly or hexadecimals and save the code reader from having to care about some `BIT` macro.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use macros like that.  You can either directly write the bit shifts:

```
enum MyEnum : uint16_t {
  first = 1 << 0,
  second = 1 << 1,
  ...
```

Or as hex, which is clearer than decimal when the values get larger:

```
enum MyEnum : uint16_t {
  first = 0x1,
  second = 0x2,
  ...
```

You probably should specify the size of the enum explicitly when you're making bitmasks, so I've added that above.

Answer (score 0):

The two pieces of code create exactly the same structure, which can be used in exactly the same way. The `BIT` macro, or spelling out `1 << 2` instead of `4`, is just an aid to humans reading the code, to signal the *intention* of the code. Whether it does a *good* job of signalling that intention is a matter of opinion.

The actual ability to use it in a "bitmask" (what you probably meant by "bitfield") doesn't come from how you write the values, but quite simply from choosing values that each have one bit set, so that you can use boolean logic to create and test different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a metafunction to generate these masks.

```cpp
template<typename T, unsigned int BIT>
struct bit_mask
{
  static_assert(std::is_integral<T>());
  static constexpr T value = T{1} << BIT; 
}
```

You could then use this metafunction:

```cpp
static_assert(bit_mask<uint8_t, 2>::value == 4);      // 0b00000100
static_assert(bit_mask<uint16_t, 8>::value == 256);   // 0b00000001 00000000
auto floatBitmask = bit_mask<float, 3>::value;        // Won't compile
```

This approach could also be extended to allow you to set multiple bits in the integer, by providing a parameter pack of unsigned ints and recursively ORing the bit shift produced by each parameter provided in the pack:

```cpp
template<typename T, unsigned int... BIT>
struct bit_mask
{
  static_assert(std::is_integral<T>());
  static constexpr T value = 0;
};

template<typename T, unsigned int BIT, unsigned int... BITS>
struct bit_mask<T, BIT, BITS...>
{
  static_assert(std::is_integral<T>());
  static constexpr T value = (T{1} << BIT) | bit_mask<T, BITS...>::value;
};

template<typename T, unsigned int BIT_A, unsigned int BIT_B>
struct bit_mask<T, BIT_A, BIT_B>
{
  static_assert(std::is_integral<T>());
  static constexpr T value = (T{1} << BIT_A) | (T{1} << BIT_B);
};
```

This can then be used:

```cpp
static_assert(bit_mask<uint16_t, 2>::value == 4);      // 0b00000000 00000100
static_assert(bit_mask<uint16_t, 8>::value == 256);    // 0b00000001 00000000
static_assert(bit_mask<uint16_t, 2, 8>::value == 260); // 0b00000001 00000100
static_assert(bit_mask<uint8_t, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7>::value == 255);   // 0b11111111
```